# Show multiple images for specific attribute in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, php, product-attribute

I have made a multiselect attribute called "Special"

For every value selection I have to show an image on the product page

I wrote the code below but it works only if I choose only one selection. When I choose more selections I have no image on fronted.

Any suggestions?

```
<?php
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$specialName = $_product->getAttributeText('special');
$specialId = $_product->getSpecial();
?> 
<?php if ($specialId) : ?>

<img src="/media/catalog/special/<?php echo str_replace(' ', '_',$specialId); ?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo $specialName; ?>" title="<?php echo $specialName; ?>" />

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What kind of loop are you using?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that I do not use a loop

Comment: Can you help me with the loop please?

Comment: have you tried what Pawan answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your code like:

```
<?php if($specialId) :?>
    <?php $Ids = explode(',', $specialId);//Multi select attribute will give you comma seprated values
        foreach ($Ids as $id) { ?>
         <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB); ?>media/catalog/special/<?php echo str_replace(' ','_', $id);?>.jpg"/>//image name should be 8.jpg/9.jpg (you can also choose label here)
        <?php } ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

**Explanation:** AS your attribute is multi selects first you need to get all values and explode them.it will give you an array.
You can iterate a loop and echo image for each attribute value.

If Have any issue feel free to ask!

**Note:** I have use is for image you can use label as per your original code.

Answer (score 0):

I edited the code from above and it worked like a charm

```
  <?php
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$specialName = $_product->getAttributeText('special');
$specialId = $_product->getSpecial();
//print_r($specialId); 
//echo "Hi";
//print_r($specialName);
//exit;
  ?> 
  <?php if ($specialId) : 
  $specialId = explode(",",$specialId); ?>
<?php for($i=0;$i<count($specialId);$i++){ ?>
<img src="/media/catalog/special/<?php echo str_replace(' ', '_',$specialId[$i]); ?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo $specialName[$i]; ?>" title="<?php echo $specialName[$i]; ?>" />
<?php } ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
```